# Instalación del paquete rf an Anaconda para Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

¡Hola!

He intentado instalar el paquete "rf" para aplicar la metodología de funciones receptoras, en Anaconda, siguiendo cada una de las instrucciones que indican en la documentación. Algunas de las dependencias ya están instaladas correctamente, pero arroja el siguiente error:

```
Building wheel for toeplitz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MSAAVE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3gc1j83s\\toeplitz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MSAAVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9hnd__oo' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building extension "toeplitz" sources
  f2py options: []
    adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.7\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\src\fortranobject.c' to sources.
    adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.7\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\src' to include_dirs.
  build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Found executable C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Users/msaavedra/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
  Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
  Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 5.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Users/msaavedra/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
  Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
  Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 5.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
  building 'toeplitz' extension
  compiling C sources
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for toeplitz
  Running setup.py clean for toeplitz
Failed to build toeplitz
Installing collected packages: toeplitz, rf
  Running setup.py install for toeplitz ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MSAAVE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3gc1j83s\\toeplitz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MSAAVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lg50qgj6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building extension "toeplitz" sources
    f2py options: []
      adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.7\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\src\fortranobject.c' to sources.
      adding 'build\src.win-amd64-3.7\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\src' to include_dirs.
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Found executable C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Users/msaavedra/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
    Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
    Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 5.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gfortran.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Users/msaavedra/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
    Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
    Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/include/c++/5.3.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 5.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
    customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
    building 'toeplitz' extension
    compiling C sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\msaavedra\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MSAAVE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3gc1j83s\\toeplitz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MSAAVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lg50qgj6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MSAAVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3gc1j83s\toeplitz\
```

Pensé que solo necesitaba unos compiladores de fortran, por lo que también instalé MinGW para ver si se solucionaba el problema, sin embargo, no tuve éxito. En este caso no estoy segura si el paquete no funciona en un ambiente Windows, que es desde donde estoy trabajando con Anaconda.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda!!!

Comment: Instala en netframework 4

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado mucho con Anaconda últimamente, pero por lo que he encontrado, parece que se necesita instalar SciPy de cierta forma para que funcione.

Hay personas a las que instalar SciPy mediante `conda install scipy` en lugar de pip les resuelve este problema [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589566/236345).

Suelen hacer todo el proceso dentro de anaconda, es decir:

```
conda install numpy
conda install pandas
conda install scipy
```

En otros casos, intentan bajar compilaciones no oficiales para windows (que igual son populares y suelen funcionar) de [este enlace](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) y las instalan con pip install `<libreria_whl>`

Fuentes: 
[enlace 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492810/statsmodels-installation-no-module-named-numpy-distutils-msvccompiler-in-num)
[enlace 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860484/236345)

Comment: Anaconda viene con esos paquetes instalado

Comment: @JackNavaRow entonces ha mejorado esa cosa y a la OP le faltan son los redistributable de Visual C++ :/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Alfabravo. Efectivamente esos paquetes ya vienen instalados con Anaconda.